# Restrict datepicker dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

Currently I have this javascript code for my date picker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#datePicker").datepicker();
        $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

How to make my date picker not accept the past date? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this greys out (and disables the selection) of any past date:

```
 $(function () {
            $("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker(
            {
             minDate: +0,
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

[minDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate) option does this work..